# What is better data structure for project

Tags: reactjs, data-structures

I am new to programing. Right now I am developing SPA with react. It is pretty simple. I am trying to choose between different data structures.
First:

```
 {
  subject1: {
    category1: {
        subcategory1: {
           item1: {
              key1: prop1,
              key2: prop2
           }
         }
    }
  },
subject2: {
  category2: {
     subcategory2: {
       item2: {
         key1: prop1,
         key2: prop2
       }
     }
   }
},
```

}

Or:

```
[
  {
   subject1: "ddd",
   category1: "ddd",
   subcategory1: "ddd",
   key: prop,
   key: prop,
 },
 {
   subject2: "ddd",
   category2: "ddd",
   subcategory2: "ddd",
   key: prop,
   key: prop,
 },
{
   subject1: "ddd", // subjects, categories and subcategories may repeat
   category3: "ddd",
   subcategory3: "ddd",
   key: prop,
   key: prop,
 }
]
```

Based on that structure I am going to form navigation based on drop-down list.
Can you advise me what is better to choose and what is better to maintain.

Comment: Every Data structure has advantages in some operations. Like in array is easier than linkedlist for insertion and deletion.
So choosing will entirely depend upon which operation will be performed more frequently